# Help with a boot problem

Tags: boot, usb, kali

Ok this is an interesting problem. I have a bootable usb with kali linux on it and I would like to run it on my computer that is running ONLY buntu 14.04. It is an old mac but so I am not sure if that makes a difference. If I plug in the usb it just boots into ubuntu. Any ideas how I can change the boot options? To be clear this computer no longer has mac osx on it is an ubuntu only computer.

Comment: You're sure the USB partition has the `boot` flag set properly ? This is what happened to me once.

Comment: @Videonauth I think so..

Comment: @Videonauth Yes it is bootable

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter bios and change it so that the USB is the first bootable drive. Since all computers are different it's hard to say how to access bios. The usual keys are `Delete Esc F2 F8 F10 or F12`

Depending on how old it is .. it may not even have the capability to boot from a USB. If it has a CD in it.. I may try using that instead.

Comment: Thanks I know it can because I installed ubuntu using a bootable drive the problem is that I have only ubuntu and I cant find answers to how to boot into bios in ubuntu. Should I just try some of those buttons when it boots up? When do i push them after I see ubuntu boot screen or right after i push the power button?

Comment: booting into bios doesn't matter what OS you use. BIOS is basic input output system .. its the "motherboards" OS that runs before the actual OS. If you aren't sure which key you have to press when you start your computer .. just try  one at a time ... turn on your computer and start imediatly tapping the delete key over and over .. if you see ubuntu starting then that key didn't work or you missed it .. its usually a small window.. just keep trying with the other keys i listed .. you should either get to bios or see a boot menu screen that will allow you to choose which drive to boot too

Comment: Ohhh ok I didnt know that ;)

Comment: the reason for the tapping is .. if you hold the key .. you can get a "keyboard error" but tapping doesn't do it and as i said there is a small windows where you can access it .. but its hard to know when that is unless the computer says at the bottom during the initial boot (before ubuntu) that says something like `press F2 for setup   press esc for boot menu`

Comment: Ok so when I hit esc it brings in GNU grub which is like a terminal so is that the wrong one?

Comment: basically you missed it or its not the esc key ... like i say . .this is the MB's OS so if it gets into the installed OS in any manner then you either missed the small window or it wasn't the right key .. what kind of computer is it . its an old Mac I know but what model ..I know nothing about Macs but maybe I can find the right key to get into bios if I knew the exact model

Comment: It's a late 2007 macbook

Comment: ok this makes no sense  to me but hopefully it makes sense to you .. after the chime hold the options button down until you get a boot menu

Comment: I found it but there is only Ubuntu I don't see a USB option so I guess I will have to just mess around with it

Comment: Oh wait hang on I did the option thing and I think it found it

Comment: So it sees the USB but when I click on it it boots Ubuntu ... So is there a problem with the USB then?

Comment: yeah sound like it ... how did you make the USB .. you may have to try it again ... I like Rufus but that's a Windows program so if you only have Ubuntu, you wont be able to use that one.

Comment: I used dd that's installed in Ubuntu already

Comment: Could it also be a problem that im trying to run 32bit but my ubuntu is 64?

Comment: ahh I have to admit .. I have never tried to create a bootable USB from Ubuntu so I don't know the procedure sorry, I won't be able to help you there .. .The thing I read about getting the boot menu said that Macs use UEFI with is a newer version of the older BIOS that older computers had. Not sure if they used UEFI in 2007 but if that is the case and you have the option when creating the disc for either MBR or UEFI boot ... you may try UEFI or if you did use UEFI on that USB then try the other way .. again .. not sure if you have that option when creating it in the Ubuntu program

Comment: that could be .. again it may be the UEFI thing ... UEFI is not easy and doesn't play well with 32 bit Ubuntu .. I know I have seen that they suggest you using 64 bit and there is a special section on how to set it up if you are  using a 32 bit version .. If you have a 64bit computer I would use a 64bit OS anyway... sorry this is only guessing on my part.. as i said .. i dont know macs so I may be completely wrong on this

Comment: You have been super helpful so far!! I am downloading a 64 bit version now and going to try it and see if it works better if not. Oh well :) I will just have to keep researching lol